# configuring reinforced-typings to add custom typescript intersection type

Tags: reinforced-typings

I am using the reinforced.typings fluent configuration API (pleural methods) to map my C# DTOs to typescript interfaces, generating a single file.

currently i am getting the (correct) output such as

```
export interface ICourseDto
{
   start: Date;
   facultyMeetingRoom: IRoomDto;
   courseParticipants: ICourseParticipantDto[];
   ...
}
export interface IRoomDto ...
```

ideally, I would like to:

1. add `import breeze from 'breeze-client'` to the beginning of the generated typescript file
2. alter the type of the complex properties, such that the output above would become

-

```
export interface ICourseDto
{
    start: Date;
    facultyMeetingRoom: IRoomDto & breeze.Entity;
    courseParticipants: (ICourseParticipantDto & breeze.Entity)[];
    ...
```

is this possible with the reinforced.typings fluent configuration, and if so, what configuration code do I need to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way to achieve what you want is (where s is ConfigurationBuilder):

```cs
s.Global(a => a.UseModules());
s.AddImport("breeze", "breeze-client");

var mySpecialTypes = typeof(IBreezeEntity).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(d => typeof(IBreezeEntity).IsAssignableFrom(d));

foreach (var type in mySpecialTypes)
{
    s.Substitute(type, new RtSimpleTypeName($"I{type.Name} & breeze.Entity"));
}
```

Reinforced.Typings also preserves inheritance. Consider deriving your entities from common type/interface and exporting it also.

Comment: Thank you. Very workable solution, however you suggest a much better idea regarding deriving the entities from a common type - I have posted a question relating to how to achieve that here if you don't mind looking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604955/configuring-reinforced-typings-to-extend-a-class-unrelated-to-server-inheritence