# configuring reinforced-typings to extend a class unrelated to server inheritence pattern

Tags: reinforced-typings

I have a simple DTO like so

```
public class MyDTO {
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I wish all my typescript interfaces used by the client to have the properties of MyDTO on the server, and also extend [BreezeJS entity type](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/inside-entity.html). that is, the output for the typescript file should become

```
export interface IMyDTO extends breeze.Entity {
    name: string
}
```

But the server/ .NET type is a simple POCO (i.e. does not derive from any classes), because the members of the BreezeJS.Entity type purely relate to managing the entities on the client/in an ECMAScript environment.

How do I achieve this with Reinforced.Typings fluent API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using following code generator:

```cs
public class BreezeCodeGenerator : InterfaceCodeGenerator
{

    private static readonly RtSimpleTypeName BreezeBase = new RtSimpleTypeName("breeze.Entity");

    public override RtInterface GenerateNode(Type element, RtInterface result, TypeResolver resolver)
    {
        var b = base.GenerateNode(element, result, resolver);
        if (b == null) return null;
        b.Implementees.Add(BreezeBase);
        return b;
    }
}
```

And apply it to your POCOs as follows:

```cs
public static void Configure(ConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ExportAsInterfaces(
        //or generate IEnumerable of desired POCO types somehow else
        new[] { typeof(BreezeEntity1), typeof(BreezeEntity2) }
        ,
        d => d.WithPublicProperties().WithCodeGenerator<BreezeCodeGenerator>());

}
```

Comment: hi, how can I make it generate an import statement of breeze.Entity at the top of the file? thank you